# IntervalSlider and updating function specification

Tags: front-end, dynamic, gui-construction, scheduling

`IntervalSlider` seems to ignore `Dynamic's` second argument:

```
x = {0, 1};

Slider @ Dynamic @ x[[1]]         (*works well*)
Slider @ Dynamic[x[[1]], None]    (*works well, locked*)
IntervalSlider @ Dynamic[x, None] (*wrong, should be locked but isn't*)

Dynamic @ x
```

`IntervalSlider` should be locked the same way the second `Slider` is. That is not the case.

Is it a bug, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say it was a bug.  Here's a workaround:

```
IntervalSlider@Dynamic[x, # &]
```

The sliders move when dragged but pop back to the original setting when released.  I don't like that, but maybe it's supposed to do that.

*Update*

The bug seems to be in `` NotebookTools`ControlsDump`extractFunction ``:  The case where a single `None` is passed for the update function(s) is not handled, and the call defaults to the equivalent of

```
Dynamic[x, {None, Automatic, None}]
```

Another possible workaround is the following, which is what a simple `None` should have been mapped to:

```
Dynamic[x, {None, None, None}]
```

Yet another fix is to extend the internal function to handle `None`, but that's not a safe fix, IMO:

```
NotebookTools`ControlsDump`extractFunction[which_, None] := Null &;
```

Comment: Yes, I agree, already reported. Wanted to post it here for future reference. Also the problem seems to be deeper, in case of `foo` in place of `None` it will be ignored unless we transform it too `foo[#]&` which indicates sloppy implementation.

Comment: I faced this because my code was not working: `IntervalSlider[Dynamic[x, {foo, bar}]]`. Based on `extractFunction` it is clear that `foo[#]&` is needed but I don't think that is expected.